# TemplateBinding fails when the target is an ImageBrush.ImageSource

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, templatebinding

Why does `TemplateBinding` seems to fail in this specific case?

Take a basic extended button:

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IconButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IconButton);
    }
}
```

The control template shows the icon using an `OpacityMask`:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:IconButton">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IconButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This fails silently -- the control appears as a solid rectangle.  If I use a regular image, instead of the `ImageBrush`, then the binding is successful:

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IconButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

It also works correctly if I hard-code the image source path:

```
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:IconButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                               Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/appbar.next.rest.png" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

So, why does `TemplateBinding` fail inside an `ImageBrush`?

---

**Update**

By deduction (and thanks to the answer from Chris), possible factors are:

- [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) inherits [from `DependencyObject` rather than from `FrameworkElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4861659/1001985)
- `TemplateBinding` does not support implicit type conversion in the way that a normal binding does (ie, string-to-ImageSource)

I still don't see how the dots connect, though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I managed to replicate that behaviour from your example, and although I can't be entirely sure, I think I might understand what's going on.

Based on the answers to this question: [WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent) it seems that although 
two methods achieve the almost same thing, they differ in some key behaviours. The most relevant one being mentioned by Miroslav Nedyalkov -

> "TemplateBindings don't allow value converting. They don't allow you
>   to pass a Converter and don't automatically convert int to string for
>   example (which is normal for a Binding)."

I would guess that in the second case, thebinding will use the built in WPF convertor to convert the bound `string`/`URI` to an `ImageSource` (usual behaviour when specifying an `ImageSource` - it's why you don't usually need to specify a binding convertor).

In the first case, you won't get the default value converting, so you won't see the mask. Interesting to see if it would work if a convertor was specified.

Edit: It looks there might be some additional complications from `ImageBrush` not inheriting from `FrameworkElement`: [Bind an ImageBrush to a template with a DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861659/bind-an-imagebrush-to-a-template-with-a-dependencyproperty)

Comment: nice find -- that issue of type conversion would seem to explain it.  The only thing that still has me scratching my head, is why `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ... />` is able to bind.  You'd think `Image.Source` would fail, for the same reason that `ImageBrush.ImageSource` fails -- seems to be an anomaly.

Comment: Hmm, you're right - I've added an edit, looks like there might be something else going on.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a workaround.  Bizarrely, using the `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` binding instead of `TemplateBinding` fixes the issue.

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Icon}" />
```

Theoretically that is the exact same binding ... so, who knows?  Whatever works.